# How to pass a tab id to a URL with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see in the code below, I'm trying to pass the value of a tab's id to a URL. In this example, I'm outputting it to HTML just to show an example, but the hashtag id isn't getting passed to the URL on my local site.

**Expected Result:**
mysite.com/#jared

I left the `location.hash = $(this).attr("href");` in there (commented out) so you can see what I'm trying to do.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

```js
var url = document.URL;
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#"));

$(".nav-tabs")
  .find("a")
  .each(function (key, val) {
    if (hash == $(val).attr("href")) {
      $(val).click();
    }

    $(val).click(function (ky, vl) {
      result.textContent = $(this).attr("href");
      //location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h5 id="result"></h5>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#jeff">Jeff</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#nate">Nate</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#jared">Jared</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#general">General</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content mt-3" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="jeff">
      <h5>Jeff's Stuff</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nate">
      <h5>Nate's Stuff</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="jared">
      <h5>Jared's Stuff</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="general">
      <h5>General Stuff</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong... but is it just that you are triggering the click before you've bound the click handler?

```
$(".nav-tabs")
  .find("a")
  .each(function (key, val) {
    if (hash == $(val).attr("href")) {
      $(val).click(); // click handler is bound later!
    }

    $(val).click(function (ky, vl) {
      result.textContent = $(this).attr("href");
      location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});
```

If you do it like this, it will probably work as expected:

```js
var url = document.URL;
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#"));

$(".nav-tabs")
  .find("a")
  .each(function (key, val) {
    $(val).click(function (ky, vl) {
      result.textContent = $(this).attr("href");
      location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    });
    if (hash == $(val).attr("href")) {
      $(val).click();
    }

  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h5 id="result"></h5>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#jeff">Jeff</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#nate">Nate</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#jared">Jared</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#general">General</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content mt-3" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="jeff">
      <h5>Jeff's Stuff</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nate">
      <h5>Nate's Stuff</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="jared">
      <h5>Jared's Stuff</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="general">
      <h5>General Stuff</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```